# Can I pass data using PopViewControllerAnimated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to pass a `NSString` from one view controller to another when calling "popViewControllerAnimated".

I have this in `ScheduleExerciseViewController`:

```
    CalendarMainViewController *controller = [[CalendarMainViewController alloc]init];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSString *fromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:self.dateCellsManager.startDate];
    NSLog(@"fromDate: %@", fromDate);
    [controller setPutDateHere:fromDate];


    //Pop the controller view controller
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

In `CalendarMainViewController.h` I have:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *datesWithEvent;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *putDateHere;
```

And In `CalendarMainViewController` I have:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.tabBarController.title = @"Calendar";
    NSLog(@"putDataHere: %@", _putDateHere);
    NSLog(@"datesWithEvents: %@", _datesWithEvent);
}
```

It prints "null" in both.

Any suggestions/comments/feedbacks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't pass data using that method. You can do it the easy way using NSNotification (highly recommended). Or you can do it the hard way and subclass your navigation controller and create a custom method that pops to a specific view controller and take whatever parameters you want (not recommended).

Also, You are instantiating a new CalendarMainViewController instead of finding the old one on the stack. I recommend iterating through the stack

```
for (UIViewController* vc in self.navigationController.viewControllers){
    if ([vc isKindOfClass:[CalendarMainViewController class]]){
         [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:true];
    }
}
```

Lastly, set class properties like this:

```
controller.putDateHere = fromDate;
```

Setters and getters are old school :)

Comment: Thanks, I decided to use NSNotification and I was able to get the data. Thanks for your help!. I can't vote up your comment because I have less than 15 reputation -_-.

Comment: I understand. I'm glad it worked out. See if you can give me the green check. Good luck :)

Comment: Finally! I have 16 reputation now. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Storyboards, another way you can pass data when going back to a previous view controller is using an **unwind segue** and then passing the data in the `prepareForSegue:` method.